# What are all the different *titles* for finishing the campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

I know there is the *Casual Campaign Ace*, but:

- What are all possible titles?
- What are the requirements for each?
- If you first achieved one, and then you play the campaign again, can you get another (higher I assume, as there is only one slot)?

I'm talking about this thing in the profile:

[image]

Comment: Are you expecting something more than "<Difficulty Level> Campaign Ace"?

Comment: @Raven, well, I don't know whether "Casual" means having beaten it in easy or normal difficulty for example.

Comment: What did you play? :D Casual I believe is easy, as when you start a mission there are 4 difficulties listed. "Casual" "Normal" "Hard" "Brutal"

Comment: There is no "easy" difficulty -- "easy" difficulty is called "Casual". :P. I take it you beat the game on "casual" then?

Comment: Oh, I did not remember easy was called casual :) -- I am playing hard, but I haven't finished it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Possible titles: `<difficulty> Campaign Ace`, so the titles are:

  - Campaign Not Complete [[example](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/383164/1/DuckloadRa/)]
  - Casual Campaign Ace [[example](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/789884/1/SeleCT/)]
  - Normal Campaign Ace [[example](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/1011852/1/Fenix/)]
  - Hard Campaign Ace [[example](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/361977/1/Firebear/)]
  - Brutal Campaign Ace [[example](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/288325/1/TheLittleOne/)]
- Exact requirements: not entirely sure, but I believe that getting the "Wings of Liberty" achievement unlocks the first title, and the appropriate "Liberty Completionist: " unlocks subsequent ones.
- Upgrading existing titles: the title is upgradable, you need to play all the missions on higher difficulty settings. You don't actually have to start a new game, just use the archive.

Comment: I have heard from some sources that the "normal" one is bugged though I can't confirm

Comment: Would I need to restart the campaign or using the archive would be sufficient?

Comment: @Juan I'm almost certain just using the archive is sufficient.

Comment: I can confirm this -- I finished the campaign and got the Casual title, apparently one mission was not reported to Battle.net as completed (although I had it played in the archives); I replayed it, and got the Hard Campaign Ace.

Comment: @juan manuel: The real bug (with using the archives) is that it doesn't correctly count the number you've completed, until you complete the last mission. I got through the last mission, and I got 5 achievements (5 brutal, 10 brutal, etc, etc).